# How to change email signature using GMAIL API?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

I want to setup email signature for each user in the domain. The thing is I already have a html signature ready but I dont know how to use html signature with GMAIl API. I am using python and when I try to do that, it only converts it to text. Is there any way to embed html signature in a variable which then inserts into the gmail account using GMAIl API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I found the solution to use html signatures. What I did is created html files using python script (You can also create them in any other way. I just did using python because I wanted a single script to create a html signature as well as change the email signature for the user).

And then imported whole html as text inside a python variable as shown below.

```
file = open(test.html, 'r')
    htmlfile = file.read()
    ESignature = {'signature': htmlfile}
```

After that in the email signature body parameter I just used the variable where I stored the html signature and it worked.

```
sig = service.users().settings().sendAs().update(userId='me', sendAsEmail="test@example.org", body=ESignature).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the documentation [Managing signatures](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#python)

```
primary_alias = None
aliases = gmail_service.users().settings().sendAs().\
    list(userId='me').execute()
for alias in aliases.get('sendAs'):
    if alias.get('isPrimary'):
        primary_alias = alias
        break

sendAsConfiguration = {
    'signature': 'I heart cats'
}
result = gmail_service.users().settings().sendAs().\
    patch(userId='me',
          sendAsEmail=primary_alias.get('sendAsEmail'),
          body=sendAsConfiguration).execute()
print 'Updated signature for: %s' % result.get('displayName')
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs) states it should be HTML

[image: TBH Im not sure if there is any way to force it to convert to HTML it seams it only supports text.]